# Arduino conexão MQTT através de leitura de file

Tags: arduino, mqtt

Na conexão com o server mqtt usando a biblioteca PubSubClient, consigo conectar normalmente usando:

```
#define servidor_mqtt "192.168.15.24"
```

Só que desse jeito fico atrelado a usar sempre o mesmo endereço para o broker.

Sendo assim, fiz um programa que lê o IP do broker e salva em um file para quando iniciar a conexão usar esse parâmetro.

O problema é que não está conectando, mesmo sendo iguais tanto o IP estático quando o de leitura.

```
// rascunho 

STATIC_SERVER_MQTT = f.readStringUntil('\n');<br>
char cserver[STATIC_SERVER_MQTT.length()];<br>
STATIC_SERVER_MQTT.toCharArray(cserver, STATIC_SERVER_MQTT.length()+1);<br>
char* serverMqtt = cserver;<br>
client.setServer(serverMqtt, 1883);
```